# Why is there an enormous strain provided there is a very little stress after the elastic limit is passed?

Tags: atomic-physics, stress-strain

Take a look at the stress-strain graph

[image]

(Source - mechanicalbooster.com)

Nearby point $D$, if you apply a little force on the object, then it’s length will increase at a very rate as compared to the initial rates.

Why and how does this happen at an atomic scale? Do the atoms get somewhat far away from each other that it becomes easier to separate them or is there some other reason for this to happen?

Also, can you please explain roughly, what is the minimum distance between the atoms of a rope or a string such that if the distance between the atoms become more than this specific distance, then the rope will break.

Comment: Necking (reduction in cross-sectional area) occurs.

Comment: @Farcher, how would that make strain go up at a huge rate?

Comment: Because the stress $\frac FA$ would increase as area $A$ has decreased so you can actually reduce the force $F$ and still get an increase in length.

Comment: @Farcher, If this was true then once the area starts to decrease then the strain would continuously go up at a nice rate. But it doesn’t. It only does so in some places in the graph! Why is that so? 

Is it that there is necking on different parts of the rope at different times which causes this phenomenon?  And when one of that area becomes too small, the rope breaks?

Comment: Does this help? https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=10&ved=0ahUKEwjVrMXQlIrSAhXjIsAKHfZNCOgQFghAMAk&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.researchgate.net%2Ffile.PostFileLoader.html%3Fid%3D5531dffccf57d7f0788b45bf%26assetKey%3DAS%253A273759695507457%25401442280806223&usg=AFQjCNEW7jOkDxVkRCFMCi4PQXaICoIelg&sig2=XSCTOKPNypfqZel4XAozUQ&bvm=bv.146786187,d.ZGg&cad=rja